# What is it called when a fluid will "jump" to grab onto an object that comes very close?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, forces, experimental-physics, terminology

I'm doing an experiment where I bring a probe very close to a well full of fluid and then very slowly lower it to obtain some force deformation values. The material behaves very much like a fluid and when I bring the probe close to the fluid, it sort of jumps up and grabs the probe and forms like a "column?" that actually pulls on the probe rather than pushing on it.

Anyway, I'm trying to coat the probe with an oil or something that will prevent this, but I don't know how to look into it because I don't know what its called or how its described in the literature. Any ideas on what this phenomena is called?

Comment: Adhesion? There's probably a more technical term for it, that's just what I know from basic chem.

Comment: Surface tension?

Answer (score 3):

It's called [adhesion](http://enwp.org/Adhesion). If the fluid you're working with is water, wax is a good option. It 'repels' water. In the general case, you want to maximise the [contact angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_angle) for the liquid and the surface. For more water-repelling materials, see [hydrophobe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrophobe) and [superhydrophobe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superhydrophobe).

If the same experiment had to do with a jet of water sticking to a surface, it's called the [Coandă effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coand%C4%83_effect). It's part of the *actual* reason that planes fly. You may also want to see [the shower-curtain effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shower-curtain_effect) (this page has multiple reasons for a certain phenomenon, some of which you may want to look at)

Similar phenomena are [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28chemistry%29) and [surface tension](http://enwp.org/Surface_tension).

Comment: Whoops.  Updated; I didn't realise that the Coanda is only for a jet.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to try such words as "surface tension", "wettability", "capillary action".

Comment: I think wetting is really what you are looking for. Of interest is the behaviour of the contact line, this is not described by surface tension alone